# How to access map keys through index? Dart

Tags: dart

```
dartques = {'Color':[], 'Fruits':[], 'Hobbies':[]};
```

How to access the values using index in map?
I need to access only key or value using index.
Just like we do in list
`=>list[1]`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter/Dart: How to access a single entry in a map/object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53824755/flutter-dart-how-to-access-a-single-entry-in-a-map-object)

Answer (score 26):

you can get it like this

```
var element = dartques.values.elementAt(0);
```

also for Dart 2.7+ you can write extension function

```
extension GetByKeyIndex on Map {
  elementAt(int index) => this.values.elementAt(index);
}

var element = dartques.elementAt(1);
```

Comment: what have i done so far??! this is the way.. [:

Answer (score 21):

For accessing the values by index, there are two approaches:

1. Get Key by index and value using the key:

   ```
    final key = dartques.keys.elementAt(index);
    final value = dartques[key];
   ```
2. Get value by index:

   ```
    final value = dartques.values.elementAt(index);
   ```

You may choose the approach based on how and what data are stored on the map.

For example if your map consists of data in which there are `duplicate` values, I would recommend using the first approach as it allows you to get `key` at the index first and then the `value` so you can know if the value is the wanted one or not.

But if you do not care about `duplication` and only want to find a value based on Index then you should use the second approach, as it gives you the value directly.

**Note**: As per this [Answer By Genchi Genbutsu](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60521753/8112679), you can also use Extension methods for your convenience.

**Important**: 
Since the default implementation for `Map` in dart is `LinkedHashmap` you are in great luck. Otherwise Generic `Map` is known for not maintaining order in many programming languages.

If this was asked for any other language for which the default was `HashMap`, it might have been impossible to answer.

Comment: Great answer, thank you. Indeed the key is that dart's `Map` defaults to  a [LinkedHashmap](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.10.5/dart-collection/LinkedHashMap-class.html) which keeps the order.

Answer (score 16):

You can convert it to two lists using `keys` and `values` [methods](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.3.1/dart-core/Map-class.html):

```
var ques = {'Color':['a'], 'Fruits':['b'], 'Hobbies':['c']};
List keys = ques.keys.toList();
List values = ques.values.toList();
print (keys);
print (values);
```

The output:

```
[Color, Fruits, Hobbies]
[[a], [b], [c]]
```

So you can access it normally by using `keys[0]`, for example.