# Firebase realtime database and Listview builder in flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase-realtime-database

I have a problem. It is getting data from firebase realtime database. If data is added it throws an error.

> _TypeError (type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int' of 'index')

According to the image below that has been flattened
[image]

realtime databse Json in my code patient_ID is "1264758392012"

```
{
  "notification": {
    "1264758392012": {
      "-NWD2baVxumoarhIVQS6": {
        "calling_by": "Nurse",
        "is_read": true,
        "misscall": true,
        "timestamp": "2023-05-24 20:59:11.535176"
      },
      "-NWD2rEc8eGGaOF72fCF": {
        "calling_by": "Nurse",
        "is_read": false,
        "misscall": true,
        "timestamp": "2023-05-24 21:00:15.649757"
      },
      "-NWD3tqlVO5TDmOuHOoR": {
        "calling_by": "Nurse",
        "is_read": false,
        "misscall": true,
        "timestamp": "2023-05-24 21:04:48.450108"
      },      
    }
  }
}
```

realtime database

```
void realtime()async {
  final ref = await FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref();
    ref.child('notification/$patient_ID').onValue.listen((event) {
      final snapshot = event.snapshot;
      if (snapshot.exists) {
        setState(() {
          // dataNotification.clear();
          data = snapshot.value as Map<dynamic, dynamic>;
        });
        setState(() {
          dataNotification.clear();
          dataNotification.addAll(data.values);
        });
        print("dataNoti: $dataNotification");
      } else {
        print('No data available.');
      }
    });
 }
```

Listview.builder

```
ListView.builder(
  key: UniqueKey(),
  physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
  padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
  shrinkWrap: true,
  itemCount: dataNotification.length,
  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context,int index) {
    final itemDataNoti = dataNotification[index];
    return Container(
      height: 80,
      width: double.infinity,
      child: Card(
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
          child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),
                child: Icon(
                  Icons.phone_missed,
                  color: Colors.red,
                ),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20),
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    itemDataNoti == null ?Text("data") :Text(
                      "calling by: ${itemDataNoti["calling_by"].toString()}",
                      style: GoogleFonts.notoSansThai(),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  },
)
```

Comment: It looks like the data at `notification/$patient_ID` in your database, is not what the code expects it to be. Can you edit your question to show this data (as JSON text, no screenshots please)? You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in the overflow menu (⠇) on your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).

Comment: I have added the json data to my post for you. Is it the one you want?

Answer (score 0):

Your code reads this JSON data:

```
{
  "calling_by": "Nurse",
  "is_read": true,
  "misscall": true,
  "timestamp": "2023-05-24 20:59:11.535176"
}
```

Which you then parse with:

```
data = snapshot.value as Map<dynamic, dynamic>;
```

So the keys in your `data` map are strings (`"calling"`, "`is_read"`, etc), not numbers.

You try to access values in `data` by a numeric index here:

```
itemBuilder: (BuildContext context,int index) {
  final itemDataNoti = dataNotification[index];
  ...
```

This isn't possible (as they are string values), so the runtime throws an error indicating this mistake.

---

If you want to show the individual properties in a list view, you can [use `values`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/1.10.1/dart-core/Map/values.html) to get a list of the values in the map, and then [use `elementAt`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/1.10.1/dart-core/List/elementAt.html) to access the map items by index. Something like:

```
itemBuilder: (BuildContext context,int index) {
  final itemDataNoti = dataNotification.values.elementAt(index);
  // Now you can access the key and value of itemDataNoti
  ...
```

Also see: [How to access map keys through index? Dart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60512845/how-to-access-map-keys-through-index-dart)

Comment: I tried changing to 
` final itemDataNoti = dataNotification.elementAt(index); `
But it's still the same.

Comment: "it's still the same" is hard to help with. It also seems unlikely that you'd get the exact same error message after the code change. Please be specific and detailed. Also note that the code in my answer is `dataNotification.values.elementAt(index)`, which is not the same what you shared.