# How to get the length for each list according to its key inside map

Tags: flutter, dictionary, dart

how to get the length for each list according to its key
Map mymap= <String, List>;

Example
key1 : 5(length of the value(list))
key2 : 48

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53824755/10157127),

you can do `mymap['k1']?.length`, here `?.` means it will return null if there is no value.

Rest you can follow @zabaykal's answer.

```dart
 Map<String, List> mymap = {
    "k1": [1, 2, 4],
    "k2": [5, 6, 7],
    "k3": []
  };

  print(mymap['k1']?.length);

  mymap.forEach((key, value) {
    print('$key: ${value.length}');
  });
```

Comment: it giving me 1 each time and its not true

Comment: does  `forEach` method answer your question? Can you explain more details by updating question including sample input and output

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a second map with the original keys and the respective lengths as the value you can use the following code where `initialMap` is the original map with `List<T>` as values:

```dart
final mapListCount = initialMap.map((key, value) => MapEntry(key, value?.length));
```