# Flutter #6 : How can I call the elements in this list?

Tags: flutter

After passing data via `connectRequest`
I get a string of values

```
final connectRequest = ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguments ;
   print(connectRequest);
```

this is after i printed out `connectRequest`

```
{serialNumber: HKGHGH, modelName: GW020H, ipAddr: 192.168.1.1}
```

How can I call the elements in this list ?

Comment: Please make an effort to describe the problem in your question title.  Your pattern of "Flutter #X: How can I achieve this?" is completely generic and prevents other people with the same problem from searching for your question.  Additionally, people who might know the answer to your question might ignore it completely.  Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: What does it mean to "call the elements"?

Comment: I want to get the values ​​in the list like 'serialNumber' , 'modelName' and 'ipAddr'

Answer (score 0):

Its a `Map` you can access element like:

```
print(connectRequest['serialNumber']);
```

output:

```
HKGHGH
```

Map is `key : values` which you can call key to get value you
[Can follow this question to read more](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53824755/flutter-dart-how-to-access-a-single-entry-in-a-map-object&ved=2ahUKEwjmuIraksj6AhUAxQIHHSeaACEQFnoECA8QAQ&usg=AOvVaw3d87s5uG-raNYSvLd2zp0T)

Comment: as soon as i do this i get an error which is "The method '[]' can't be unconditionally invoked because the receiver can be 'null'.
Try making the call conditional (using '?.') or adding a null check to the target ('!')."  I also tried adding the ! and ?. however I get another error "The operator '[]' isn't defined for the type 'Object'.
Try defining the operator '[]'."

Comment: Can you attach what you are passing to `ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguments`?

Comment: Future<void> connectDevice(Data data) async {
    var connectRequest = {
      'serialNumber': data.serialNumber,
      'modelName': data.modelName,
      'ipAddr': data.ipAddr,
    };
    print('------------$connectRequest');
    var apiEndpoint = API.shared;
    var res = await apiEndpoint.connectDevice(connectRequest);
    print(res);
    Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const DeviceInformation(),
    settings: RouteSettings(arguments: connectRequest),
    ));
  }

Comment: Well, use `final Map connectRequest = ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments as Map;` and try what happens

Comment: If didnt help, change `var` into `Map` in where you are passing to new page

Comment: Glad to hear that, if my answer helps, vote to help others too