# need to print "it" and "mt" values in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a Map data.

```
Map<String , Map<String, List<int>>> data = {"value":{"it":[ 1666117800000,1666204200000,1666290600000 ],
  "mt":[1666463400000,1666549800000,1666636200000]}};
```

I want to print it and mt values form this Map.

Comment: `print(data['value']?['it']);` & `print(data['value']?['mt']);`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter/Dart: How to access a single entry in a map/object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53824755/flutter-dart-how-to-access-a-single-entry-in-a-map-object)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

accessing value from map is by using the key

```
 print(data['value']?['it']);
  print(data['value']?['mt']);
```

use `?` means its nullable value

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
void main() {
  Map<String , Map<String, List<int>>> data = {"value":{"it":[ 1666117800000,1666204200000,1666290600000 ],
  "mt":[1666463400000,1666549800000,1666636200000]}};
  
  
  for (var it in data["value"]!["it"]!) {
    print(it);
  }
  print("");
  
  for (var mt in data["value"]!["mt"]!) {
    print(mt);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
void main() {
  Map<String, Map<String, List<int>>> data = {
   "value": {
      "it": [1666117800000, 1666204200000, 1666290600000],
      "mt": [1666463400000, 1666549800000, 1666636200000]
    }
  };

  Map<String, List<int>>? _value = data['value'];

  print(_value);
  print(_value!['it']);
  print(_value!['mt']);
}
```