# How to access an object of a map in a widget in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

How can I get a single entry from a map to give it to the widget in Flutter?

For an example:

```
Map<String, String> text = {
    "text1" : "Text 1",
    "text2" : "Text 2"
}
```

```
home: Center(
    child: Text(text["text1"])
)
```

This shows error. I can't access the key of the map.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter/Dart: How to access a single entry in a map/object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53824755/flutter-dart-how-to-access-a-single-entry-in-a-map-object)

Comment: also, post the exact error message you're seeing.

Comment: All the accesses used in the page you provide link to, are in the print statement. That will print the text in the debug console but I want to pass that text in a widget which will be shown when I run the app, on the screen of the device (Android or iOS).

Comment: Only you had to add not null check [doc](https://dart.dev/null-safety/understanding-null-safety)! Only if you had add the error/issue message. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ensure you imported `import 'package:flutter/material.dart'`

```
Map<String, String> text = {
    "text1" : "Text 1",
    "text2" : "Text 2"
}
```

Add a null checker

```
home: Center(
child: Text(text["text1"]!))
```